# How to transfer many files from Android to Windows Phone without accept each file?

Tags: bluetooth

I tried to send multiple video files from my Android phone to my Windows Phone 8.1.

Each time I have been asked to accept or ignore the transfer, unfortunately I pressed the ignore option in the middle of transfer. I checked the files in pictures > saved picture folder, but none of them are received,

I checked the same using another Android phone and same thing happened, did anyone notice this issue?

Comment: Does it work if you send them again?

Answer (score 2):

You have to accept every file that should be transferred - there is no way around this at the moment. I guess this might have security reasons, but you still can post your question to http://windowsphone.uservoice.com

Old answer:

The transfer will be stopped if you hit ignore and the file(or what has been transferred already) will be discarded. This is not really an error but by design. Try resending those files and don't dismiss the transfer dialogue.

Comment: I think the problem is that he needs to accept every file even though the sender is trying to send a bunch of files. I experienced the same.

Comment: You mean the issue is that by ignoring one of the files all files get discarded?

Comment: No. That when you try to send a bunch of files from Android to WP it ask permission for every file. Android to Android it ask only once.

Comment: I see, but I'm not really getting that from his question...

Comment: @Thomas I think the question is actually in the title; not the question.

Comment: Right, I guess reading that one helps ;-) will update my answer accordingly.

Comment: @Thomas actually I had edited before we started to discuss 

Comment: @Drowin Sorry, I edited.

Comment: I think you're right about the security. Because, in the event that a virus could indeed get on the phone, an app could pass the virus to other phones without the user realizing it. This way you can see each file that is transferred.

Answer (score 1):

You could use shareit, and before transferring, both the devices must be connected with same WiFi connection.